# wxPython: Name error

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm trying to follow Listing 1.3 from the book 'wxPython in action'.

I believe I've written an exact copy of the code:

```
"""Hello, wxPython! program."""

import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    """Frame class that displays an image."""

    def __init__(self,image, parent=None, id=-1, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, title='Hello, wxPython!'):

        """Create a Frame instance and display image."""
        temp = image.ConvertToBitmap()
        size = temp.GetWidth(), temp.GetHight()
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size)
        self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(parent = self, bitmap = temp)

class App(wx.App):
    """Application class."""

    def OnInit(self):
        image = wx.Image('wxPython.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
        self.frame = Frame(image)
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

    def main():
        app = App()
        app.MainLoop()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

...but I get the following error message when I run the code:

```
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 254, in run_nodebug
  File "\\ri-file-2\cst$\image.py", line 28, in <module>
    class App(wx.App):
  File "\\ri-file-2\cst$\image.py", line 43, in App
    main()
  File "\\ri-file-2\cst$\image.py", line 39, in main
    app = App()
NameError: global name 'App' is not defined
>>>
```

Can anybody figure out what's wrong - thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` subroutine and `if __name__ == '__main__'` bit now belong to `App` class due to wrong indentation. Take them out by deleting preceding four spaces:

```
        ...
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

def main():
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, make sure that you have `wxPython.jpg` file in the program folder, otherwise the program won't run.

PS. In this line of the code:

```
    size = temp.GetWidth(), temp.GetHight()
```

it should be `GetHeight()` instead of `GetHight()`.